# Unresolved dependency SBT play#sbt-plugin;2.0: not found Play examples on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, playframework-2.1

I have problem with pushing example app to heroku cloud.
I did everything like I read here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ProductionHeroku

Unfortunately I got error: http://pastebin.com/N7N2JCDY

Any idea how to make it work?

I would add I saw: 
[Unresolved dependency SBT org.scala-sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.12.1: not found, Play examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737926/unresolved-dependency-sbt-org-scala-sbtsbt-2-9-10-12-1-not-found-play-exampl)

It didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the version of your play plugin in project/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" %  "2.1.3")
```

2.1.3 is the latest release, I dont see a 2.0 in

http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/

Comment: Strange thing is I'm still getting "play#sbt-plugin;2.0: not found" error, even after I changed it in project/plugins.sbt file.